# Проверка входимой матрицы на корректность

Tags: f#

Подскажите пожалуйста, как при данной реализации ввода разреженной матрицы (через 2 Array.Fold) проверить матрицу на корректность (чтобы длина каждого ряда была постоянной). Матрица бинарная, проверку на бинарность я уже сделал. Всем добра!

```
  let readMatrix file =
    let processLine (str: string) (i, lst) =
        str.Split ' '
        |> Array.fold (
                       fun (j, lst) c ->
                           if c = "1"
                           then (j + 1, I(i * 1<_rows>, j * 1<_column>) :: lst)
                           elif c = "0"
                           then (j + 1, lst)
                           else failwith "Matrix has incorrect format")
                        (0, lst)

    let mtx =
        System.IO.File.ReadAllLines file
        |> Array.fold (fun (i, lst) str -> (i + 1, processLine str (i, snd lst))) (0, (0, []))
        |> snd

    mtx
```

Comment: У вас что-то не в порядке с алгоритмом. Проверьте тип результата.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin про это я в курсе, сейчас он возвращает int * list, но это не проблема. я мог бы добавить |> snd в первый Fold и существенно упростить код, но в будущем мне ещё понадобится длина ряда и колонки, поэтому так.

Comment: Проблема не в паре, проблема в том, что `list` - это не матрица

Comment: А! Или вы представляете матрицу в виде списка координат ненулевых элементов?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, да именно так. Разреженная матрица

Comment: Но в таком случае понятие "корректности" в вашем определении как "длины всех рядов равны" не имеет смысла. Раз вы не записываете каждый ряд явным образом, можно считать, что каждый ряд (да и каждая колонка) бесконечен, уходя нулями в бесконечность справа.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin по сути Вы правы, но в формате этого задания предполагается, что отсутствие 0 или 1 совсем не значит то, что на этом месте должен находиться 0.

Comment: В таком случае, вы видимо имеете в виду, что надо проверить на "корректность" не результирующую матрицу, а ввод с консоли?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin да, прошу простить меня за неточную формулировку, надо проверить именно ввод с файла

Comment: Я ответил на англоязычном сайте: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64950436/180286